# When getting maxid from table name

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Declare @Id bigint  
EXEC procGetMaxNumber @Id output,'employee'
```

I'm getting an error message

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

when I execute the procedure with the above parameters

```
 -- =============================================    
    -- Description: <Fetches Max Id for a particular table>    
    -- =============================================    
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procGetMaxNumber]    
(    
  @Id BIGINT OUTPUT,  
  @TblName nvarchar(50)    

 )    
 AS    
 BEGIN    
 SET NOCOUNT ON;    

 Declare @Query nvarchar(max) = ''  
 set @Query =  'SELECT ' + @Id + ' = isnull(Max(Id),0)+ 1 from '  +   @TblName  
 --print @Query  
 Exec (@Query)  
 END
```

Comment: Care to share what that error message says? I'm guessing it might point to your problem.

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure procGetMaxNumber, Line 16
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: Please show us the schema of your `employee` table.

Comment: What is the purpose of getting the "next" Id value from any table? What kind of guarantees do you expect about what that value is now and what it might be when you get around to inserting? (Hint: there are no guarantees.)

Answer (score 2):

This looks extremely dangerous to me. What exactly are you going to do with the "next" Id value once you get it? You know that immediately after you retrieve this value, someone could insert a row and take it (or even fail to insert a row, and still take it even if the transaction rolled back), right? If you want to reserve an Id value and be sure that is the number you get, just run the insert, don't do any of this max+1 to insert later.

Anyway you can't use `EXEC` to retrieve an output parameter from dynamic SQL, you'll need to use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @Id = COALESCE(MAX(Id),0)+1
  FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TblName) + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@Id INT OUTPUT', @Id OUTPUT;
```